# Can't access array index in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

this Component is mapping an array and I am passing **index** of array via onClick in another function and after console i got Object.

And I really dont know about it...

> Here is Component

```
const MonthName = () => {
 return <>
   {month.map((nameOfMonth , index) => 
    <div key={index}  onClick={() =>CurrentMonthDates(index)}>
    <Link to="/yearMonth" >
    <div> 
      <h3>{nameOfMonth}</h3>
      </div>
      </Link>
    </div>)}
    </>
```

here where I pass index

```
const CurrentMonthDates = (index) => {
 console.log(index)
}
```

See Image this object i got

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MjP4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your example from the beginning:

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MonthName />
        <Route path="/yearMonth" component={YearMonth} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

let month = ["Jan", "Feb", "March"];

const MonthName = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {month.map((nameOfMonth, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => YearMonth(index)}>
          <Link to="/yearMonth">
            <div>
              <h3>{nameOfMonth}</h3>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const YearMonth = (index) => {
  return <div>{console.log(index)}</div>;
};
```

Our goal is to create an app, that displays a list of month-names as hyperlinks **(MonthName Component)**, and on clicking any of those links, we should navigate to the **YearMonth** component.

Now, what happens when a link of a month is clicked. Two events are generated, a **routing** event and an **onClick** event registered in a **div**. And both events are passed to the functional component **YearMonth**.

So, when the **onClick** event executes, it passes the current index into the functional component, and therefore it gets logged.

Now, when routing event is triggered, the statement

```
<Route path="/yearMonth" component={YearMonth} />
```

is executed, and component **YearMonth** is rendered. But when using, react-routing mechanism, the **Route** components always pass a routing object to the component they render, as a function parameter. In this case, the **YearMonth** component. And since the **YearMonth** component accepts a single parameter, the index parameter
now points to this object and therefore it gets logged.

A simple way to solve this is to replace the **YearMonth** component, in the **onClick** handler with a new function, and remove logging from the **YearMonth** component.

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MonthName />
        <Route path="/yearMonth" component={YearMonth} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

let month = ["Jan", "Feb", "March"];

function yearMonth(index){
  console.log(index);
}

const MonthName = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {month.map((nameOfMonth, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => yearMonth(index)}>
          <Link to="/yearMonth">
            <div>
              <h3>{nameOfMonth}</h3>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const YearMonth = () => {
  return <div>Hi</div>;
};
```

To learn more about how routing works, [follow this article](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

Comment: Charchit this Object i got only when i add <Link> of React-router..without <Link> i can easily access.

Comment: Hi Kamlesh, I think the problem lies in the way you are mapping objects. Your component contains a Link component within it, and the utmost div and the Link both are clickable. So whenever, you click it two events are shot at once, try mapping it directly to Link object. Try logging the event object, within the onClick function, it might give valuable insights.

Comment: Try to provide a bit of your source code, it will really help to understand what is happening underneath.

Comment: Hi Charchit if i return Link and map all JSX inside Link the problem still remain same to me.

Comment: here in this component im mapping..
http://pastie.org/p/6k65IrNMQu05DWc59077dr

passing Index here;
http://pastie.org/p/2Yiss9yHsq3plsJzsnb32b

Comment: Try to implement a minimal version of it here. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new), and then share it. In this way, I will be able to execute it as well.

Comment: Charchit I m just a beginner and its very hard to share full code because lots of file and feature and where is error how will you know

Comment: Check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-minsky-fj546?file=/src/App.js). I created a minimal version, and it is working as expected. Make sure to check all the logs.

Comment: Thanks to understand Chrachit I appreciate your effort.
check this https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-chatelet-6f371?file=/src/yearMonth.js this is what I am getting.
and i dont want this object.

Comment: Thanks, Charchit... Link pass a prop in a component automatically...
and exactly we don't pass it.. so it better to create a new Function.